Modeling specific triangular folds on clothes
I want to recreate a specific effect of folds on clothes from a reference. The folds have a recognizable triangular shape and many straight lines. I ask you to suggest a way to recreate the folds as close as possible.

Even if the topology ends up being just awful, it won't be such a big deal.

It's not gonna be super simple, I would start with a cloth sim to get yourself close, then sculpt any extra detail, then flatten the surfaces, sharpen the creases and maybe the do a Decimate modifier set to Planar. The last step is only necessary if you actually need it to be flat faces, and will absolutely wreck the topology. It's possible you could get the final stylized look in shading instead of going for actual geo.
